# SAPUI5: data binding from master1 to master2

Tags: datacontext, sapui5

I am trying to create a Simple Fiori Like UI using SAPUI5. I want to implement Master1->Master2->Details Scenario. The problem is When I navigate from Master1 to Master2, no data shows up.

Master.view.xml

```html
 <core:View
 controllerName="sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.Master"
 xmlns="sap.m"
 xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" >
 <Page
  title="{i18n>MasterTitle}" >
  <subHeader>
      <Bar>
          <contentLeft>
              <SearchField
                  search="handleSearch"
                  width="100%">
              </SearchField>
          </contentLeft>
      </Bar>
  </subHeader>
  <List
      id="assemblyLines"
      mode="{device>/listMode}"
      select="handleListSelect"
      items="{/MaterialCollection}" >
   <StandardListItem
    type="Navigation"
    press="handleListItemPress"
    title="{Code}"
    description="{Desc}"/>
  </List>
 </Page>
</core:View>
```

Master2.view.xml

```html
<core:View
 controllerName="sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.Schedule"
 xmlns="sap.m"
 xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" >
 <Page
  title="{i18n>ScheduleTitle}" 
  showNavButton="true"
  navButtonPress="handleNavButtonPress" >
  <subHeader>
      <Bar>
          <contentLeft>
              <SearchField
                  search="handleSearch"
                  width="100%">
              </SearchField>
          </contentLeft>
      </Bar>
  </subHeader>
  <List id="jobs" items="{LineItems}"
          mode="{device>/listMode}">
      <ObjectListItem
          type="{device>/listItemType}"
    press="handleListItemPress"
    title="{Material}"
    number="{OrderQty}">
          <attributes>
              <ObjectAttribute text="{
                  path: 'PriorityDate',
                  formatter: 'sap.ui.demo.myFiori.util.Formatter.date'}" />
          </attributes>
      </ObjectListItem>
  </List>
 </Page>
</core:View>
```

App.View.js

```js
sap.ui.jsview("sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.App", {

 getControllerName: function () {
  return "sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.App";
 },
 
 createContent: function (oController) {
  
  // to avoid scroll bars on desktop the root view must be set to block display
  this.setDisplayBlock(true);
  
  // create app
  this.app = new sap.m.SplitApp();
  
  // load the master page
  var master = sap.ui.xmlview("Master", "sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.Master");
  master.getController().nav = this.getController();
  this.app.addPage(master, true);
  
  var schedule = sap.ui.xmlview("Schedule", "sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.Schedule");
  schedule.getController().nav = this.getController();
  this.app.addPage(schedule, true);
  
  //this.app.addMasterPage(master).addMasterPage(schedule);
  
  // load the empty page
  var empty = sap.ui.xmlview("Empty", "sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.Empty");
  this.app.addPage(empty, false);
  
  // load the detail page
  var jobDetails = sap.ui.xmlview("JobDetails", "sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.JobDetails");
  jobDetails.getController().nav = this.getController();
  this.app.addPage(jobDetails, false);
  
  // done
  return this.app;
 }
});
```

Please advise me about the error.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error you get in the console ?

Comment: Can't tell by the code you posted. Post the code of the two controllers otherwise it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your first view, you have set the aggregation that you are binding:

```
items="{/MaterialCollection}
```

but in your second view, you are tying to access the model properties without the slash.

```
items="{LineItems}"
```

try changing it to

```
items="{/LineItems}"
```